# Fourier series for a wave on an infinite string?

Tags: waves, fourier-transform, boundary-conditions, superposition

From "Vibrations and Waves" by A.P. French I know that any wave on a string length $L$ can be represented by: 
$$y(x,t)=\Sigma^\infty_0 A_n \sin(\frac{n\pi x}{L})\cos(\omega_nt-\delta_n)$$
But can we generalise this to an infinite string. I.e. could I say:

> Any wave on a string of any length (including an infinite string) can be presented by: $$y(x,y)=\Sigma^\infty_0 A_n \sin(k_n)\cos(\omega_nt-\delta_n)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point of restricting the string to length $L$ is that we can then construct a periodic function (with wavelength $L$) by imagining repeated copies of the string connected to each other. In this case we can construct the function as a [Fourier series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series) with the lowest frequency sine/cosine having the same wavelength $L$.

If we have an infinite string then the function need not be periodic (though of course it may be). If the function is not periodic we can still use a Fourier description, but in this case it is a [Fourier transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform) not a Fourier series.

Comment: If the function is periodic would the Fourier series take the form that I have stated?

Comment: Furthermore why does the wave need to be periodic on an finite string. Could we not have a wave packet that just moves along the string gets to the end and rebounds, is this still periodic?

Comment: @Joseph That gets into the transients of the system, which I have been told appear as complex values when you take the fourier transform.  The purely real-valued Fourier transform always assumes a periodic signal as part of its construction.